# How to auto pause JWplayer after 15sec of playing?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, jwplayer

I'm looking for javascript to auto-pause JWPlayer on my wordpress blog after 15sec of playing.
I currently have content locker that pops after 15sec & video starts to play automatically on page load, I basicaly need it to stop at the time of content locker poping.

Maybe it is possible to pause video at the time of content locker poping up not after 15 sec. that might turn out not so synchronised?

I came up with better code that executes WHEN content locker pops up (div "overlay_div"). But something still doesn't work.

```
if (document.getElementById("overlay_div")) {jwplayer().stop();}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a callback using `onPlay(callback)` which would get triggered as soon as the player starts playing. Additionally, you will need a variable to keep track of how many seconds have bene played so far (let's call this `secondsPlayed`).

In the callback function for `onPlay`, you use an interval of 1 second. Each time the interval code gets called, you increment you `secondsPlayed` variable by 1.

As soon as the `secondsPlayed` variable reaches `15`, you can stop playback using `pause(state)` and execute custom Javascript. You should also disable that interval at this point since you've already handled how the `15-second playback` at this point.

You can find a detailed description of all the functions I mentioned on the [Javascript API Reference page for JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference).

Comment: Can you please set up the template? I'm not so familiar with javascript at all. I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @user1829531: Fixed the answer (I originally misread the question). Can you update your original question with the code you have so far?

Comment: I don't have anything so far, Im very unfamiliar with JS. I can adjust template but i am unable to write something on my own

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `timeupdate: function(event){}`. 
inside that check the `duration` and pause the player.

but this `timeupdate` event do not work every 1ms. So it will not give you the best option to sync.